# Is there a word for the length of time an animal stays with parents before going off on their own?

Tags: terminology, general-biology

Gestation is a word describing the pregnancy for animals, and you can use 'gestation period' to describe how long a pregnancy generally takes for a species. I'd like to know if there's a corollary word for the time an animal stays with its parents before leaving.

For example, after birds are hatched, they stay in the nest for a while, but they eventually leave the nest. Is there a single word or phrase that is used to describe the time between hatching and leaving the nest? I imagine different bird species have different periods, and other animals (that don't stay within families their whole life) can also be describe in a similar matter. Perhaps 'puberty', though I'm guessing there's a more specific word.

Answer (score 2):

As you talk about bird, most of the terminology I am suggesting below comes from the ornithology literature.

**Fledging period**

Defined on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fledge):

> Fledging is the stage in a volant animal's life between hatching or parturition and flight.

**Nestling period**

Defined in [Kouba et al. (2015)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4368509/):

> In altricial birds, the nestling period is an important part of the breeding phase because the juveniles may spend quite a long time in the nest, with associated high energy costs for the parents.

**Rearing period**

See its usage in for examples [Yuan et al. (1994)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8072921) and [Brickell et al. (2009)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0093691X09001587)

**Juvenile**

While the term juvenile does not refer to a period of time, you can refer to this concept as the period while children are still juvenile. From [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/juvenile)

> a young bird in the stage when it has fledged, if altricial, or has replaced down of hatching, if precocial.